# autokey - strange issues does not work on browser and thunderbird

Tags: autokey

I have autokey-gtk installed on my Linux Mint Xfce 21 laptop that has been working fine for couple of years. Since a few days I am facing very strange issues that I am sure are unrelated to Autokey.

The phrases get expanded but the browser behaves as though they are not. For e.g., I have stored a local html file location in a phrase and use the phrase in title bar and hit space (trigger character for the phrase) I can see the full path but if I hit the return key I see a "File not found" error.
If I type the phrase+space in an editor, copy it and paste it in the browser it works!

Will be grateful if someone can give a hint on what could be the problem.

Nitin